# Differentiability implies continuity proof with little-o notation

Tags: derivatives, proof-verification, continuity, proof-writing, alternative-proof

I was trying to prove that differentiability implies continuity using little-o notation. I don't know if I'm totally right, but this is what I did so far:

For differentiability we have that:
$$
f(x)=f(x_{0})+f'(x_{0})(x-x_{0})+o(x-x_{0})
$$

Instead continuity states that:
$$
f(x)=f(x_{0})+o(1)
$$

So we can say that:
$$
f'(x_{0})(x-x_{0})+o(x-x_{0})=o(1)
$$

So, using little-o definition we have that:
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{f'(x_{0})(x-x_{0})+o(x-x_{0})}{1}=0
$$

Which should be true. Am I right? Is this a valid proof? :)

Comment: What are you asking? What proof? It depends what level are you at that $f'(x_0)(x-x_0) = o(1),$ for me, this requires no proof whatsoever.

Comment: I'm asking if my proof for differentiability implies continuity of a function is right. However I know that $f'(x_0)(x-x_0) = o(1)$ is obviously true. What do you mean by level?

Comment: Well, if you are in first year university, then maybe this is not good enough, if this is for personal use, this is good enough. On the other hand, I would write the _entire_ proof as "Clearly $f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+o(h)=f(x)+o(1).$ Q.E.D.$"